# Dynamic loading options in select2 4.0.3

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

Hi javascript experts.

I'm trying to fetch a set of options via a ajax get reguest, and insert the results as a set of options in a select2 dropdown list.

Having looked at all the questions on SO regarding this, and followed the official select2 guide (https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data) leaves me a bit puzzled, i've extracted a simple example that illustrates the problem.
Also tried using a hardcoded array instead of the data returned from the ajax call.

```
<html>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#ArbiterId").select2();

            FillArbiters(true);
        });

        function FillArbiters(eloOnly) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/MasterData/Arbiters", dataType: "json",
                data: { 'eloOnly': eloOnly },
                type: "get",
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $("#ArbiterId").select2({ data: data.arbiters });
               //     $("#ArbiterId").select2({ data: [{ id: 0, text: 'dummy' }] });
                }
            });
        }
    </script>

    <body>
    <form>
        <select id="ArbiterId" name="ArbiterId"></select>
    </form>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

The output from the ajax looks like this:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "arbiters": [
    {
      "text": " name 1",
      "id": 11446
    },
    {
      "text": "name 2",
      "id": 10786
    }
.....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out i was trying to initialize the `#ArbiterId` as a select2 box twice, which are not allowed (would be nice if select2 informed me about that)

The correct way to dynamically change the options is to first destroy the select2 box, and then recreate it, e.g. changing

```
$("#ArbiterId").select2({ data: data.arbiters });
```

to

```
$("#ArbiterId").select2('destroy').empty().select2({ data: data.arbiters });
```

more information about this topic can be found here: 
https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/2830

(answering my own question in case someone else with the same problem comes around)